# Text Editor's menu not fully visible

Tags: gnome, gedit, text-editor

On Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with GNOME 3.36.8 I just noticed that the default (Gnome) text editor gedit 3.36.2 cannot display it's menu when the menu is higher than the window.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1ZXp.jpg)
(It seems adding screenshots directly does not work at the moment)

Do others perceive the same? How to get around it?

Comment: There needs to be some detail for this question. What version of Ubuntu? What text editor?

Comment: In later versions, the menu always pops down, so I cannot exactly reproduce the issue. It will also be cut off if the window is small and near the bottom of the screen. GTK4 applications in contrast will adapt and have the menu pop up to the top if there is no room downwards.